# Prevent Image from stretching beyond actual size

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-10, uwp

I have an `Image` control bound to a source. Here is what I want:

- If the source image is smaller than the Grid containing it, it should display at its original size. It should not stretch beyond 100%. This is behavior of setting `Stretch="None"`.
- If the source image is larger than parent Grid, it should be resized uniformly to fit the container. This behavior is available with `Stretch="Uniform"`.

I have tried to bind MaxWidth and MaxHeight to parent's actual dimensions as follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ImageDataTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Grid x:Name="ImageWrapper" Grid.Row="1" Tapped="ImageWrapper_Tapped" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="AliceBlue">
            <Image Source="{Binding Link}" MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ImageWrapper}" MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=ImageWrapper, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

However, I just end up with no image at all. Parent Grid occupies all available space as can be seen from background color. But there's no image.

Is there a way to achieve behavior I want?

Comment: Slap it into a [ViewBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox)

Comment: @ChrisW. Can you give details? How would I make the ViewBox smaller if the image is smaller than available area?

Comment: Like Clemens shows below, it will keep your image the size of the space without neglecting its resolution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put the Image in a Viewbox control and set the Viewbox's `StretchDirection` to `DownOnly`. The `Stretch` property of the Viewbox has a default value of `Uniform`, so you don't need to set it.

```
<Viewbox StretchDirection="DownOnly">
    <Image Source="{Binding Link}" Stretch="None"/>
</Viewbox>
```

---

Perhaps worth to note, in WPF you could directly set the `StretchDirection` of the Image control, and thus would not need a Viewbox.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Link}" StretchDirection="DownOnly"/>
```